# Null result while use and operator in MYSQL IN

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query to get filter data from user table where category will fetch from another table.

```sql
SELECT * FROM jobfia_users 
WHERE country_id='4' 
  and user_id IN (SELECT worker_id 
                  FROM jobfia_worker_skills 
                  WHERE skill_id = '42'
                 )
```

This is not giving any error, but not return any row also.
while there are lots of records are available in table using this filter.

Can any one help please ?

Comment: Show your few records of both the tables and table structure

Comment: when you run that query directly on the database you do get the records?

Comment: Your `country_id` and `skill_id` are `varchar` type or `int` type ?

Comment: country_id and skill_id are  int

Comment: So, remove `'` around `4` and `42`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the quotes surrounding your INT ids, your query will be better expressed like this :

```sql
SELECT u.* 
FROM jobfia_users  u 
INNER JOIN jobfia_worker_skills ws 
        ON ws.worker_id=u.user_id AND ws.skill_id = 42
WHERE u.country_id=4
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `country_id` and `skill_id` are `int` type, remove `'` around values.

```
SELECT * FROM jobfia_users 
WHERE country_id=4
  and user_id IN (SELECT worker_id 
                  FROM jobfia_worker_skills 
                  WHERE skill_id = 42
                 )
```

Comment: I think mySql can handle it with or without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code with and without '' and it works. Make sure you have data and you did not misspell some column name.

Maybe you have collision of some column names. Try to use this syntax:

```
\`table_name\`.\`column_name\`
```

Code:

```
SELECT *  
FROM `jobfia_users` 
WHERE `jobfia_users`.`country_id`='4' 
  AND `jobfia_users`.`user_id` IN (SELECT `jobfia_worker_skills`.`worker_id` 
                                   FROM `jobfia_worker_skills` 
                                   WHERE `jobfia_worker_skills`.`skill_id` = '42')
```